# SQL Server database move to another server

Tags: sql, database, move

I have two SQL Server databases that are being used for my application.

The issue is that now we have decided to move one of the databases to another new server due to performance issues.

What's the best method to ensure all the joins in the SQL queries will work correctly? Do I need to update each join between the databases to so it can reference the database on the new server?

I have already updated web.config with the change but this wont affect the joins in the queries

Any advice would be great

Thanks

Comment: This is a substantial change. Expect greatly reduced performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need to configure the second server as a linked server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx

Queries on the first server can then be updated to access tables on the second.

Be aware though, any queries that join tables across the two servers will usually be *very* slow - more so if the tables have large numbers of rows.

Comment: OK, So I would need to manually update each query after setting up the linked server?

Comment: yes, after setting up the link your table names would change from the format `owner.schema.tablename` to `server.owner.schema.tablename`